# IllegalArgumentException using Spring Data and MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

We're using MongoDB and Spring Data in our Spring Boot app. Another developer has earlier written a service, using MongoTemplate's findAndModify method, and some additional code that uses that service. It worked fine, even in production.

I've branched and went on adding some new features (completely new code) and needed to call that service. Service doesn't work for me, even though I didn't even touch the service code. Moreover, even the code the other guy wrote before (it's a REST controller calling the service) doesn't work now. On the master branch, everything works like it should.

Here's the service:

```
@Autowired
private MongoTemplate mongo;

public void addRetention(Date when, String userId, Platform platform) {
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(when.getTime()/1000, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC);
        int yyyymm = 100 * dateTime.getYear() + dateTime.getMonthValue();

        Retention r = mongo.findAndModify( // the exception is coming from this line
            new Query(Criteria.where("userId").is(userId).and("yyyymm").is(yyyymm)),
            new Update().inc("count", 1).set("platform", platform),
            new FindAndModifyOptions().upsert(true).returnNew(true), Retention.class
        );

        addRealTimeRetention(userId, r, yyyymm);
    }
```

How I call the service:

```
retentionService.addRetention(timeService.timeToUtil(usage2.getDate()),
    usage2.getUserId(), platform);
```

And the [stack trace](https://pastebin.ca/3875068) on PasteBin. The exception message is:

```
IllegalArgumentException: Target bean is not of type of the persistent entity!
```

EDIT: Here's the Retention.java class:

```
@Document
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@CompoundIndexes({
    @CompoundIndex(name = "userid_yyyymm_idx", def = "{ userId: 1, yyyymm: 1 }")
})
public class Retention {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Indexed
    private String userId;

    @Indexed
    private int yyyymm;

    private int count;

    private Platform platform;

    // setters and getters...
}
```

FINAL EDIT: I solved this by deleting spring devtools dependency in pom.xml. I'm not sure how that dependency has anything to do with this exception. Found the solution [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3279). Thank you to everyone who helped out.

Comment: What is `mongo` in `mongo.findAndModify()`? It's supposed to be a collection object in the context you are calling it. The naming suggests that this is not what it is, and that's the part you are not understanding.

Comment: @NeilLunn mongo is MongoTemplate. I'll add that to the code snippet.

Comment: Could you paste the Retention.java just to check annotations

Comment: @kimy82 Sure, added it.

Comment: In MongoTemaplate used anywhere else, like in another class?

Comment: @JoseMartinez Yes, in a few. I'm only using insert, find, upsert, remove with it. Do you think the exception has anything to do with that?

Comment: I think  the Retention is  not correct and then the retention doc is not persistent. I would rewrite the compount indexes. For example  _@CompoundIndex(def = "{'userId':1, 'yyyymm':1}", name = "userid_yyyymm_idx")_  and remove single @Indexed if using compound Indexes. I would also check log file and look where entities are loaded to see if there are errors

Comment: @kimy82 I found the solution, added the edit into the question. It was the devtools dependency, it was ok when I excluded it. However, I'm not sure how that dependency has anything to do with that exception. Thank you for helping.

Comment: If you figure out why maybe you can answer your own question.  I'm sure other people might run into this problem.  I use both these technologies and would like to know how devtools affect mongo,

Comment: @JoseMartinez I really don't know how the two are connected. I found the solution in the link linked in the question, however that issue was opened in 2015, has no explanation, and the bug was supposed to be fixed. That was the only relevant source I was able to find.